# Only two threads are getting activated in OpenMP Fortran

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

This is a huge do loop and I have privatized many variables to avoid race conditions. But, values don't match with the serial code and I tried printing out **proc_num** and observed that only 2 threads (0,1) are getting activated out of 8. I want to paste the entire code but it's too long.

OUTPUT : Code is running, but I'm only getting wrong values and only 0 and 1 are getting printed for the value of proc_num.

```
   thread_num = 8

   !$ call omp_set_num_threads (thread_num)

   .
   .
   .
   .



 !$OMP parallel do private(A_inc,T_star_tr,temp33,B_alpha,C_alpha,C_alpha_vec,&
 !$OMP del_CRSS,iter_out,iter_in,del_T_star_tau,RSS_alpha,&
 !$OMP del_gam_tau,G_n,Schmid_dum,J_n, J_n_inv,correction,&
 !$OMP check,EXP_N,CRSS_c_tau,temp12,checkouter,flag,Fp_det,Fe_det)

do vk=1,npts3
  do vj=1,npts2
    do vi=1,npts1


A_inc = 0.d0

  do vii = 1,3
     do vjj = 1,3
        do vmm = 1,3
           do vpp = 1,3
              do voo = 1,3
                 A_inc(vii,vjj)= A_inc(vii,vjj) + Fp_inv_t(vmm,vii,vi,vj,vk)* &
     F_tau(vpp,vmm,vi,vj,vk)*F_tau(vpp,voo,vi,vj,vk)*Fp_inv_t(voo,vjj,vi,vj,vk)
              end do
           end do
        end do
     end do
  end do
 !$OMP critical 
 !$ proc_num = omp_get_thread_num()
 print *, proc_num, A_inc
!$OMP end critical

 T_star_tr = 0.d0

  do vii = 1,3
     do vjj = 1,3
        do vkk = 1,3
           do vll = 1,3
              T_star_tr(vii,vjj) = T_star_tr(vii,vjj) +&
         Stiff_sam(vii,vjj,vkk,vll,vi,vj,vk)*0.5*(A_inc(vkk,vll) - IDEN_2(vkk,vll))
           end do
        end do
     end do
  end do
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: `   !$ call omp_set_num_threads (thread_num)` is not a clause, it is a subroutine call. Remove the `!$`. Also, the implementation might limit the number of available threads. How many cores do you have?

Comment: Alternatively, remove the call above and set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` in the console before running the program.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I do not see why removing the ` !$` would be necessary, or indeed why would it fix the problem.

Comment: `!$` is a directive type syntax unless I am mistaken. So there is a possible source of *confusion* more than anything else.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl `!$` is used to mark source lines that are only compiled when OpenMP is on.

Comment: As always, the errors almost certainly lie in the parts of the code you haven't shown us.  That's one of the reasons we like to have a [mcve].  Also, in what way(s) are the results wrong ?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF I admit that I only use conditional directives and not conditional compilations, I prefer it this way as all compilers I use support OpenMP anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I made it work with coarse grain parallelism. But still the values don't appear to match. I'll post that problem soon